# Check membership of list in two dimensional list

Tags: python, list, membership, dimensional

Can someone please tell me how to check membership of a list in a list.

Such:

```
if x not in y:
```

using these values:

```
y = [[7,1,0][8,8,3][2,4,7]]

x = [7,1,0] # returns false

x = [7,0,0] # returns true
```

Thanks!

Comment: I take it this is Python? If so, you need to tag it as such. Or tag whatever language you are using. It's critical to the question.

Comment: It's exactly what you wrote: `x in y`. If `x` is a list then equality will be determined by comparing each of the items.

Comment: @lurker, first post. I clicked the 'python' tab when creating my post, didn't realize it wasn't implicit. Ta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list assignment is missing the `,` between sublists, but everything else should work as expected:

```
>>> y = [[7,1,0],[8,8,3],[2,4,7]]
>>> x = [7,1,0]
>>> x in y
True
>>> x not in y
False
>>> x = [7,0,0]
>>> x in y
False
>>> x not in y
True
```